# Preventing WCF Tracing Registry Entries for RASAPI32 and RASMANCS

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, trace

We have a queue service that, for each item, will take a template `.exe` file, copy it to a unique name base on the item, and use `Process.Start` to spin the exe up.

This is done to ensure that each item runs in total isolation and doesn't kill any other items (or the service) if it dies.

This exe makes use of several WCF services. When these exes spin up, they are inserting a Tracing Key into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Tracing`. Because each exe has a unique name, this very quickly bloats the registry (eventually to multi-GB sizes). To prevent the server dying, we've got a process that deletes these keys periodically.

These keys appear to be creating automatically as a result of the WCF endpoints (the keys end with `_RASAPI32` and `_RASMANCS`). You can see this with a simple example using the default WCF Project:

**Service1.svc**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

**Program.cs (calling application)**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var svc = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        var val = svc.GetData(55);

        Console.WriteLine(val);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**App.Config (calling application)**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_HTTP" closeTimeout="00:00:30"
          openTimeout="00:00:30" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          maxBufferPoolSize="8388608" maxBufferSize="8388608" maxReceivedMessageSize="8388608"
          useDefaultWebProxy="false"  >
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="8388608"
            maxArrayLength="8388608" maxBytesPerRead="16384" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"  />
                <security mode="None"  />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:58801/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_HTTP" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
        name="Service1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Is there any way to either:

1. Disable the creation of these registry keys
2. Route the registry keys to use a specific name, rather than just the Executing Assembly name?

Comment: This does not sound very plausible, nobody ever runs millions of distinct executable files.  More likely is that you are just doing it wrong.  You'll have to move over a bit, you are blocking the view on your monitor.

Comment: @HansPassant Every item in the queue generates it's own exe that is run, and then deleted. We only compile a single exe, but then create a copy for each item.  That said, the multi-gig size is in QA today where we haven't been running the cleanup though. In prod we clean them up regularly enough that it never becomes a problem.

Comment: It is a fairly... mature... system, but one that's big enough to be difficult to rework. It's probably not how I'd do it, but it is what it is unfortunately.